# How to change jetty log configuration at run time in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using apache solr in backend to provide search in my website. As solr is using jetty as server. I have changed jetty.xml to enable request.log file. Now I have to enable it in running setup. I cannot restart solr. How I can made these changes visible in running setup.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, I have not tried, but given that Jetty use internally log4j, you can use JMX.

> Log4j registers its loggers as JMX MBeans. Using the JDK's jconsole.exe
>   you can reconfigure each individual loggers. These changes are not persistent
>   and would be reset to the config as set in the configuration file
>   after you restart your application (server).